# Show a second actionSheets right after the other not working in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

In the following code, no matter where I attach the second `.actionSheet` I cannot make them work. My understanding was that as long as they were attached to different views, it would work but that theory doesn't seem to be true.

```
struct ContentView: View {

        @State private var showFirstActionSheet = false
        @State private var showSecondActionSheet = false
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack{
                VStack{
                    Button("Show Fist Action Sheet"){
                        showFirstActionSheet = true
                    }
                    .actionSheet(isPresented: $showFirstActionSheet) {
                        ActionSheet(title: Text("First Action Sheet"), message:
                                        Text("Some message!"),
                                    buttons: [
                                        .destructive(Text("Cancel")){
                                            
                                        },
                                        .default(Text("Yes")){
                                            doSomething()
                                        },
                                        .cancel()
                                    ])
                    }
                }
            }
            .actionSheet(isPresented: $showSecondActionSheet) {
                ActionSheet(title: Text("Second Action Sheet"), message:
                                Text("Some message!"),
                            buttons: [
                                .destructive(Text("Cancel")){
                                   
                                },
                                .default(Text("Yes")){
                                    
                                },
                                .cancel()
                            ])
            }
        }
        
        func doSomething(){
            showSecondActionSheet = true
        }
    }
```

I tried it with two different buttons and it worked but in my case, I only have one button that triggers the first one and the second one is triggered by the first actionSheet.

Any idea what would be the best way to handle this?

Comment: How about using `confirmationDialog`? `actionSheet` is deprecated.

Comment: Wow, it was deprecated in iOS 17.2, I'm still testing in iOS17, that's why I never got the warning.  Thank you for pointing it out, I better move away from it and start looking into confirmationDialog. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just change all the `actionSheet`s in your code to [`confirmationDialog`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/confirmationdialog(_:ispresented:titlevisibility:actions:message:)-2s7pz), it works totally fine. `actionSheet` has been deprecated in iOS 17.

Instead of using factory methods from `Alert.Button`, you can just create regular `Button`s with different `role`s.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showFirstActionSheet = false
    @State private var showSecondActionSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            VStack{
                Button("Show First Action Sheet"){
                    showFirstActionSheet = true
                }
                .confirmationDialog("First Action Sheet", isPresented: $showFirstActionSheet, titleVisibility: .visible) {
                    Button("Cancel", role: .destructive) {
                        
                    }
                    Button("Yes") {
                        doSomething()
                    }
                    Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {
                        
                    }
                } message: {
                    Text("Some message!")
                }
            }
        }
        .confirmationDialog("Second Action Sheet", isPresented: $showSecondActionSheet, titleVisibility: .visible) {
            Button("Cancel", role: .destructive) {
                
            }
            Button("Yes") {
                
            }
            Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {
                
            }
        } message: {
            Text("Some message!")
        }
    }
    
    func doSomething(){
        showSecondActionSheet = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, `confirmationDialog` did the trick. Thanks a lot for pointing out the fact that `actionSheet` was deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a scenario where the second action sheet needs to be triggered by the first action sheet's button, you can modify your code accordingly. One approach is to use a state variable to control both action sheets and manage their presentation sequentially. Here's an example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showFirstActionSheet = false
    @State private var showSecondActionSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Button("Show First Action Sheet") {
                    showFirstActionSheet = true
                }
                .actionSheet(isPresented: $showFirstActionSheet) {
                    ActionSheet(
                        title: Text("First Action Sheet"),
                        message: Text("Some message!"),
                        buttons: [
                            .destructive(Text("Cancel")) {

                            },
                            .default(Text("Yes")) {
                                showSecondActionSheet = true
                            },
                            .cancel()
                        ]
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        .actionSheet(isPresented: $showSecondActionSheet) {
            ActionSheet(
                title: Text("Second Action Sheet"),
                message: Text("Some message!"),
                buttons: [
                    .destructive(Text("Cancel")) {

                    },
                    .default(Text("Yes")) {

                    },
                    .cancel()
                ]
            )
        }
    }
}
```

the "Yes" button is tapped in the first action sheet, it sets showSecondActionSheet to true, which triggers the presentation of the second action sheet.

With the adjustment, you've got the ability to control the flow of action sheet presentations based on user interactions. Adjust the logic in the second action sheet's buttons according to your specific requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but the code you provided doesn't work.